# Use "response_action" to respond to view_submission when using botkit

Tags: node.js, slack-api, botkit

I have a simple modal with view pushed using:

```
           const result = await bot.api.views.open({
                trigger_id: message.trigger_id,
                view: {
                    "type": "modal",
                    "submit": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Submit",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Request",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "blocks": [
                        {
                            "type": "input",
                            "block_id" : "accblock",
                            "element": {
                                "type": "plain_text_input",
                                "action_id": "account_name",
                                "multiline": false
                            },
                            "label": {
                                "type": "plain_text",
                                "text": "Account Name",
                                "emoji": true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
```

I need to add error to the block if certain value is entered on `view_submission`. I understand I should send response with the following JSON:

```
       {
          response_action: 'errors',
          errors: {
            "ticket-desc": 'I will never accept a value, you are doomed!'
          }
        }
```

But, how do I send it? I've tried using `bot.httpBody()`. Does this JSON need to be included as the view object? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: how do I sent it  in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bot.httpBody()` is the method you need.

Make sure that the key to the `errors` dictionary matches the `block_id` of the element you are providing an error message for.

In your case this will work:

```
bot.httpBody({
  response_action: 'errors',
  errors: {
    accblock: 'Your account name is invalid or in use.'
  }
})
```

You do not need to `JSON.stringify` the response message and indeed the process fails if you do.

Comment: Thanks, It was the block id